# how to link a workitem which is task/testcase to another workitem/task using TFS API and C#.Net code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-sdk

I could get a test case object using TFS API.Now i want to link a task id(e.g. 435567) to this Test Case object's "Affected By" link type.
Any sample code available to do this ?

I could see there is an add method  for the testcase like below , but it doesnt task id as the parameter.

```
 testCase.WorkItem.WorkItemLinks.Add(<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.workitemlink.link >)
```

any idea how to link the taskid here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/12/10/TFS-SDK-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-a-new-User-Story-with-the-implementation-%28Tasks%29-and-test-scenarios-%28Test-Case%29.aspx) will help you. It creates a new user story with some test cases.

```
var testedByLink = wiStore.WorkItemLinkTypes["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy"];
wiUserStory.WorkItemLinks.Add(new WorkItemLink(testedByLink.ForwardEnd, wiTestCase.Id));
wiUserStory.Save();
```

Comment: the link is no longer valid